# Modify the code_Plot for multiple outputs in R

Tags: r, plot

I was wondering how I can have this plots for multiple outputs. I want to have a plot () of each output in "a" separately.

```
b<- lapply(mtcars[-c(4,8,9)], function(x) lm(x ~ vs*am, data=mtcars))
a<- lapply(b,interactionMeans)
```

mtcars data set is available in R.

Comment: What is the code for `interactionMeans`?

Comment: @ shambalambala , interactionMeans is a function, as soon as you run the second line the intercationmeans will calculate and you will get the result which is "a"

Comment: Could you please add the source code of that function to your question?

Comment: Unless you make it cleat what is in `a` and what's in `a` you need to plot, it isn't easy/possible to give you a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
library(phia)
mtcars$vs <- factor(mtcars$vs)
mtcars$am <- factor(mtcars$am)

b <- lapply(mtcars[-c(4,8,9)], function(x) lm(x ~ vs*am, data=mtcars))
a <- lapply(b, interactionMeans)

tmp <- lapply(a, function(x) {windows(); plot(x)})
```

[image]

Comment: thanks so much. How can I add the variable name into the plots?